# How to properly use CMake subprojects together with Conan?

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

Let's say we have:

- `App` CMake project which uses Conan to manage dependencies (via `conanfile.txt`)
- `Lib` CMake library standalone project which also uses Conan for same purpose, lives in a separate repository
- `Lib` is a subproject of `App`
- Some of `App` and `Lib` dependencies in their own `conanfile.txt` files are same (let's say they both use `boost/1.78.0`)

In this case, `App` project fails to build with error:

```
[cmake] CMake Error at build/conanbuildinfo.cmake:1507 (add_library):
[cmake] add_library cannot create imported target "CONAN_LIB::boost_boost_contract"
[cmake] because another target with the same name already exists.
```

What's the proper way to handle such cases? When we have nested CMake subproject and both parent and nested project use Conan inside.

Comment: make conan package for `Lib` and add it to `conanfile.txt` for `App`

Comment: If you have 1 project, with subprojects. The recommended way is to use 1 conanfile.txt for both. If you use the CMakeDeps generator, it will generate 1 xxx-config.cmake file per dependency, so each of your subprojects can do ``find_package(dep)`` for the specific dependencies it is requiring, not all in conanfile.txt. Check https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/tools/cmake.html